# Two envelopes variation - first reference?

Tags: probability, puzzle

There is a lesser known variation of the two envelopes paradox where the envelopes contain different real numbers.  The experiment will be that you are randomly handed an envelope, look, and then decide whether or not you were given the larger.

Your odds of success depend on the numbers present, but surprisingly you can guarantee odds of better than 50% of getting the envelope with the larger number.  The trick is to pick a random value out of a probability function with non-zero density everywhere.  If the numbers in the envelope are $x < y$ and the cumulative distribution function $P$, then your odds of being correct will be $0.5*(1-P(x)) + 0.5*P(y) = 0.5 + 0.5 * (P(y) - P(x))$ which must be $> 0.5$ because $P$ is strictly increasing.

This problem was analyzed by https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2009.0312 which incorrectly in 2009 claimed that they were first to analyze it.

I know that they were wrong about the history because I first heard the problem, and solution, from Dr Laurie J. Snell at Dartmouth College in the mid-1990s.  And he said it was an old problem even then and had been published.

Can anyone find an original reference to when it was FIRST discovered?

Comment: Some references here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_envelopes_problem#History_of_the_paradox (I'm not claiming this necessarily contains the *first* such reference.)

Comment: Might be hard to sort out priority here.  Seems to me I heard the basic idea prior to $2009$ but it would have been word of mouth, I never saw it written out.  And, though the conclusion is badly counter-intuitive, the basic argument is just a line or two.  Might well be that nobody ever bothered to write it down, and even if someone did, they might not have originated it.

Comment: @AaronMontgomery The Littlewood reference to 1953 is possibly it. Can anyone verify what it says?

Comment: @lulu Well, you can find me writing it out in 1993 at https://groups.google.com/g/rec.puzzles/c/mB-KqfR6oeI/m/daNPclbx8IAJ. That was not long after I heard it.

Answer (score 1):

The Littlewood reference can be found [here](https://ia800303.us.archive.org/10/items/mathematiciansmi033496mbp/mathematiciansmi033496mbp.pdf); look at (4) on p. 4.

Comment: Thanks.  There are 2 variations there, and neither is to the one I specified. :-(

Comment: Ah, I see -- you specifically wanted the strategy for getting the odds to be over 50%. My apologies. (Unrelatedly: it seems like Littlewood's treatment of the paradox is very, *very* sloppy! But I suppose he warned us about that: "The following will probably not stand up to close analysis, but given a little goodwill is entertaining.")

Comment: It was interesting. And can easily be turned into a good DP problem.  Like 50% a 1/2 card, 25% a 2/3 card, etc.  If you can issue 100 challenges and I only have 50, what are your odds of winning with perfect play?

Comment: The second variant, of course, was sloppier still.  It isn't a valid probability distribution and so can't be rescued.